# Recursions and induction

Tags: induction

If $a(n)$ is defined by: $$a(0)=1 \quad a(1)=3\quad  a(2)=9 $$ and, for $n≥3$: 
 $$a(n)=a(n-1)+2a(n-2)+5a(n-3)$$

show:
$a(n)  ≤  3^n$

So I know that I'll have to use either Induction or Strong Induction to prove this statement. I'd begin by proving the base case for $3$, but I am not sure if Strong induction would apply better. I'm having trouble showing that the inequality holds. I obtained a formula that for $a(k)$ and $a(k+1)$ but it is not in in closed form. Would that help?

$$a(k+1)=98+7(a(3)+a(4)+...+a(k-2))+2a(k-1)$$

I'll try deriving a closed form for the recursion.

Comment: a(n) ≤ (3^n)* there is a small typo above.

Comment: If you were to find the closed form for the recursion, it will be of the form $a(n)=c_1 \lambda_1^n + c_2\lambda_2^n+c_3\lambda_3^n$ where $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$ are the roots of the polynomial $(x^3-x^2-2x-5)$ and are approximately $2.5517, -0.77585+1.16513i, $and $-0.77585-1.16513i$ respectively and $c_1,c_2,c_3$ are appropriate constants based on the initial conditions.  I think it would be easier to approach via induction using much weaker arguments than finding the exact closed form and using that approach.

Comment: Note:  I reformatted your question, check that I retained your meaning.  I didn't understand your formula for $a(k+1)$...is that meant to be true for, say, $k=4$?  Anyway, I left it as you wrote it.

Comment: Tell me... is $3^n\geq 3^{n-1}+2\cdot 3^{n-2}+5\cdot 3^{n-3}$ for large enough $n$?  Maybe if we try multiplying by $3^3$ and dividing by $3^n$ this will be easier to see.  Is $27\geq 9+6+5$?  What does what I'm asking have to do with the original question?  Why am I asking it?  How do you formulate this into an inductive proof?

Comment: Hmm, I saw right away that there were imaginary roots as solutions to the problem so that would be too difficult to work around.

Comment: (Thanks for the reformat, and it's meant to be true for any values of k=3, but since I put a(k+1) it would only make sense for values of k>3). So I'm not sure how to approach the problem from that angle: how would I use your statement @JMoravitz?

Comment: Hint: $a_n \lt a_{n-1} + 3 a_{n-2} + 9 a_{n-3}$.